# Reading Both Individual Characters of Strings and the Strings themselves Pointed to by a String Array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

> In the code below, I'm attempting to pass the string array 'char *wordArray[20]..." into the function above main that is intended to find all strings within wordArray that contain a user-input character, and print each such string.  Function "findWords" is defined to expect a constant string array, its length and the user-input character because the array will be read-only.  Following examples from the text I'm using, the bottom is a combination of methods for reading individual characters from a pointer to a string, and for reading strings from a pointer array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int arrLength = 0; // Global variable dec. and initialization


void findWords ( const char *c[], int length, char letter ) {

size_t element = 0;
size_t count = 0;

for (element = 0; element < length; element++) {

    for (count = 0; c[count] != '\0'; count++) {

        if (c[count] == letter) {

            printf("%s", c[element]);

        }

        else {

            printf("%s", c[count]);
        }
    }

    count++;
}

return;

} // End function findWords



int main (void) {

{ // Begin Problem 3

    // step 1: printf "Problem 3"
    puts("Hiya");

    // step 2: create a string array of 3 pointers to strings containing at this point, random  
       words.

    const char *wordArray[3] = { "cake", "foxtrot", "verimax" };


    char usrInp; // Holds user-input letter.

    // step 3: "Input a letter from the user."
    // This do...while loop repeats until the user has entered either a lower- or uppercase    
letter.

    do {

        puts("Please enter one lowercase letter - any you'd like\n"); // One string argument 
calls for output function puts(); rather than printf();

        usrInp = tolower ( getchar() );


    } while ( isalpha (usrInp) == 0 );

    findWords( wordArray, arrLength, usrInp );

} // End Problem 3
} // End function main
```

Comment: There seem to be several issues, one of which being that the compiler's returning a warning in regard to my comparison of 'c[count]' and 'letter', which it's identifying as type int.  I need a little help understanding how to compare a character in a char var. to a character in a string contained within a string array.  Note: Please ignore the size of *wordArray[] in the block quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at findWords :

```
for (element = 0; element < length; element++) {
    for (count = 0; c[element][count] != '\0'; count++) {
        if (c[element][count] == letter) {
            printf("%s\n", c[element]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

at main :

```
arrLength = sizeof(wordArray)/sizeof(*wordArray);//arrLength = 3;
findWords( wordArray, arrLength, usrInp );
```

Comment: Nice use of `sizeof(wordArray)/sizeof(*wordArray)`.

Comment: Great answer, BLUEPIXY; thank you very much!  And yet, I'm perplexed that I haven't come across this technique in the text.  Again, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

c[count] is char* which means you cannot compare it to a char. this pointer just holds the address to your current string. you need to traverse that string in order to check for letter.
In your code you need to change:

```
if (c[element][count] == letter)
```